# On Click preload images using javascript

Tags: javascript, preload

Directly calling preload function works without any issues. But when preload() is called onClick,even after loading of images ,not ending its processing and that can be viewed as "loading..." in a browser

```
function preload(images) {
    if (document.images) {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray = images.split(',');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        for(i=0; i<=imageArray.length-1; i++) {
            document.write('<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" width="335px" height="180px" alt="[Alternative text]" />');
            imageObj.src=imageArray[i];
        }
     }
}

<a href="javascript:onclick=preload('1.jpg,2.jpg');">Gallery</a>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly ? To preload the image so that they can be displayed instantly or to write them in the page so that the user sees them ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `document.write` after the page is loaded. If you want to add something to the page, you must call DOM manipulation functions like [document.createElement (see example)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement).

But what you do in your function doesn't look like preloading but rather like direct insertion of images in the page.

If you want to preload images, that is to ask the browser to cache them so that they are instantly available later, then you'd better use `XmlHttpRequest` instead of creating `Image` elements. Issuing `XmlHttpRequest` requests doesn't make the browser display a hourglass and the user doesn't feel like something is happening.

I made a small "library" last week-end just for this : easily preload resources.

```
var preload = (function(){
    var queue = [], nbActives = 0;
    function bip(){
        if (queue.length==0 || nbActives>=4) return;
        nbActives++;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest(), task=queue.shift();
        req.open("GET", task.src, true);
        req.onload = function () {
            nbActives--;
            bip();
            if (task.callback) task.callback(task.src);
        };
        req.send();
    }
    return function(src, priority, callback) {
        queue[priority?'unshift':'push']({src:src, callback:callback});
        bip();
    }
})();
```

Usage :

```
preload('path/to/file.png'); // preload the file

preload('path/to/file.png', true); // preload the file with high priority

preload('path/to/file.png', false, callback); // preload the file and be notified when it's finished
```

Github repository : https://github.com/Canop/preload

Comment: Sorry please check this post again

Comment: I am loading images when onClick(), because to decrease the loading time and show the images when it is required.

Comment: Ok, so I might suggest you to use the library I made. See edit.